# Magento site broke after installing new theme

Tags: php, magento

My web store broke after installing a new theme, but the error persists after changing the theme back to default.

```
 Notice: Undefined index: catalog.topnav  in /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 460

#0 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(460): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/havhokere...', 460, Array)
#1 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
#2 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
#3 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#11 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#12 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

I have no idea what could be causing this, another error I've encountered after installing the theme is in the admin panel, if I click on "categories" I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cmsmart/megamenu/menutop.phtml on line 85

#0 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cmsmart/megamenu/menutop.phtml(85): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/havhokere...', 85, Array)
#1 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/havhokere...')
#2 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#3 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#4 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#5 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(174): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Cmsmart_Megamenu_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#8 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#9 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#10 /hom    e/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#11 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#13 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#14 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#15 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#17 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#20 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#21 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#22 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#23 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#24 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#25 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Magento version: 1.9.1.1

Site: www.havhokeren.dk/magento

Comment: Can you post the contents of both the files mentioned in your errors? Also what theme did you try to install?

Comment: Hi Charles. I tried installing this template from TemplateMonster: https://www.templatemonster.com/free-magento-1-9-template.html. It doesn't seem to have a name other than "Free Magento 1.9 Template". 

Here is the contents of Layout.php: https://pastebin.com/XNmBWGMN

Comment: menutop.phtml: https://pastebin.com/uZXhD8B3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never assume variables exist. Things might change if the providers don't supply the correct values.

You might have been lucky due to caching that the error did not pop up before.

In menutop you have this on line 85

```
if($categoryArr[0]['active_product']== 1)
```

These are the assumptions your code makes:

- Variable $categoryArr is an array.
- Variable $categoryArr has at least one entry with index 0
- Variable $categoryArr[0] is an associative array
- Variable $categoryArr[0] has an index 'active_product'

That's a lot of assumptions to make.

To make it more bulletproof you'd ideally use either a helper function to access arrays with a failsafe default, or a complicated if statement

```
if(!is_null($categoryArr) && is_array($categoryArr) && array_key_exists(0,$categoryArr) && !is_null($categoryArr[0]) && is_array($categoryArr[0]) && array_key_exist('active_product', $categoryArr[0]) ){
```

or you use a helper function

```
function getValue($key, $arr, $default=null) {
   $pieces = explode('.', $key);
   $array = $arr;

   foreach($pieces as $array_key) {

      if(!is_null($array) && is_array($array) && array_key_exists($array_key, $array)) { 
          $array = $array[$array_key];
      }
      else {
          $array = null;
          break;
      }
   }
   return is_null($array) ? $default : $array;
}

$testarr = [
    ['foobar' => 'baz'],
    ['active' => false]
];
$output = getValue('0.foobar',$testarr,'NOT FOUND');
var_dump($output);
$output = getValue('0',$testarr,'NOT FOUND');
var_dump($output);
$output = getValue('1.active',$testarr,'NOT FOUND');
var_dump($output);
$output = getValue('i.do.not.exist',$testarr,'NOT FOUND');
var_dump($output);
```

https://ideone.com/11jtzj